# How can i open all my Office365 documents on the desktop as default?

Tags: office365

At my company we use Office365. When i open a document (Word, Excel, etc..) from a SharePoint site, it opens by default in the online editor in the browser. Office 2013 is installed on my desktop. I am not a site admin.

I want all office documents from Office365 to open by default in the desktop versions.

How do i configure that?

Comment: Are these SharePoint, network, or local documents?

Comment: @CharlieRB I edited my question to highlight that is relates to document on SharePoint / Offie365.

Comment: If you would have been a site admin, then there are some easy steps to achieve what you are trying to do. Can't you contact your site admin to do that for you. Then I can share the steps he should take.

Comment: Those changes are made at the SharePoint site level. Agree with @RakibulIslam. You need admin rights to change those settings. Get with the site admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll need to be a site administrator to make the changes. At first, make sure that you are on the top-level site for this site collection.

- Click the gear in the upper right-hand corner of SharePoint and select `Site Settings`.
- From the Site Settings page, under the `Site Collection Administration` section, click on `Site collection features`.
- There is an option called `Open Documents in Client Applications by Default`. Simply hit the Activate button. It will take some time to complete the activation.

Comment: So, a personal preference is not possible?